# How to get role from adalservice userInfo

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, adal

I am calling adal service in my angular component. To print details of user. I am doing adalservice.userInfo.

```
console.log(this.adalService.userInfo);
```

But, it is not returning any **'role' field** or **profile-picture** by default

In azure-ad I created 2 group named admin and user. But, do I need to send some key:value pair from group to identidy role, as it is not returning group name. Temporarily, what I think to do is I am getting some extra field for users in Admin grp(grp name).

What is the permanent fix?